# Get the Path of a resource from a spring boot aplication using servlet context

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, classpath

I have this structure, generated by spring boot

[image]

So I want to get a input stream of the file gastos.xlsx using sevletContext.

```
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext context;

    @GetMapping("/grafico")
    public ResponseEntity<String> exportExcelGrafico(HttpServletResponse response){

        try{
               //this path returns null. What is the real path to put here? 
             InputStream input = context.getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/templates/gastos.xlsx");
             //returns null
             input = context.getResourceAsStream("/resources/templates/gastos.xlsx");
             // Returns null
             input = context.getResourceAsStream("/templates/gastos.xlsx");
        }
        catch(){

        }
```

What would be the right path?
I didn't configure anything on my `application.properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in the `src/main/resources` folder of your Maven or Gradle project ends up in your jar, not in the web resources. And it should thus be loaded using the class loader, not using the servlet context:

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/templates/gastos.xlsx")
```

Not sure why you put that file under templates, since... it's not a template.